# Elif statement doesnt work

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

[image]

I seriously can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You have an indentation problem. Move the `elif` 4 spaces left.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I can't type anything after I hit enter, it moves two lines down.

Comment: -1 please paste **text** rather using an image.

Comment: @FZEROX, you can delete this question since it is smashing your reputation...

Comment: Yea sure like I care about an internet number, I actually posted an image instead of a code to make it easier for those willing to help me.Downvote a newbie for being a newbie logic.Thanks to Sukrit Kalra and  Andrew Finnell for actually answering.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong. Left indent it once and the Syntax Error will go away.

```
if < Condition Here >:
    # Do Something
    elif < Condition Here >:
```

will give a syntax error whereas

```
if < Condition Here>:
     # Do Something
elif < Condition Here >:
     # Do Something
```

is the correct indentation. Indentation matters a lot in Python.

From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html),

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

Comment: Which is the worst possible "feature" of any programming language ever.

Answer (score 2):

Your `elif` statement is not indented properly with the `if` statement:

```
if some_condition:
    #code
elif some_other_condition:
    #code
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation):

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

Example from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements):

```
>>> x = int(raw_input("Please enter an integer: "))
Please enter an integer: 42
>>> if x < 0:
...      x = 0
...      print 'Negative changed to zero'
... elif x == 0:
...      print 'Zero'
... elif x == 1:
...      print 'Single'
... else:
...      print 'More'
...
More
```

On IDLE try something like this:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> if x == 0:
    print x
elif x == 1:
    print x
elif x == 2:
    print x
else:
    print 'foo'


2
```

Comment: This didn't work as intented.

Comment: @FZEROX Or should you say, indented :D

Comment: @FZEROX I've added an IDLE related example.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separated python script, for example `tmp.py` and put most complicated sequence of commands there:

```
if something:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

save it and then run using `run tmp` if you are in `IPython` or `python tmp.py` if you are in a shell (command prompt, bash, etc).